# How to automate the task of web browsing using wget?

Tags: python, linux, shell, scripting, wget

I have a text file consisting of 100 URLs . I want to use wget with each and every URL from the text file one after the other.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself thus far? Even some pseudo-code doing what you plan to do would be helpful and show that you have attempted the problem yourself also.

Comment: Parsing is new for me. I learnt that using && , || , & operators would help me .

Comment: The URL would be the variable that would be changing constantly. I would have to use a loop so that wget would be called with a url but i just have no clue how to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
location='the/Location/of/thefile.txt'
cat '$location' | while read url
do 
    wget $url

done
```

Comment: Thank you ! I really appreciate the help. I am new and a little light shining from the end of the tunnel really helps.

Comment: Glad I could help!